# Finding most recent noon or midnight preceding x hours ago

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I have a need to get the time in seconds for the most recent noon UTC or midnight UTC preceding the time six hours before now. In other words, if it's currently 2022-05-17 04:00:00, I want the value 2022-05-16 12:00:00 to be returned (six hours before 2022-05-17 04:00:00 is 2022-05-16 22:00:00, so the most recent noon/midnight before that would be 2022-05-16 12:00:00).

I'm currently grabbing `datetime.now()`, using `datetime.timedelta()` to go back six hours, grabbing the hour and using a conditional to set midnight vs. noon, combining it all into a string then using `datetime.strptime()` to convert back to a datetime object, another `datetime.timedelta()` to check against the epoch, and finally `datetime.total_seconds()`. I figure there must be a more elegant way and I would greatly appreciate advice on shortening this code (although it does work):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
six_hours_ago = now-timedelta(hours = 6)
six_hours_ago_date = six_hours_ago.date()
six_hours_ago_hour = six_hours_ago.hour
if six_hours_ago_hour < 12:
    gribtime_to_search = '00:00'
else:
    gribtime_to_search = '12:00'
gribdate_string_to_search = f"{str(six_hours_ago_date)} {gribtime_to_search}"
gribdatetime_to_search = datetime.strptime(gribdate_string_to_search, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
epoch_timedelta = gribdatetime_to_search - datetime(1970, 1, 1)
seconds = epoch_timedelta.total_seconds()
```

Comment: whhats the use case? also how many times are you planning on rnning the code? if it's only once, I think your approach looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way could be to use `datetime.combine` to combine `date` and `time` objects into a (time-zone aware) datetime, as shown below.

I would also ensure to use `datetime` methods like `utcnow()` and `replace()` with `tzinfo` argument, so that you can ensure that you're working with UTC dates and times.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time, timezone

# now = datetime.utcnow()
now = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-05-17 04:00:00').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
print('Input:', now)

six_hours_ago = now - timedelta(hours=6)

six_hours_ago_date = six_hours_ago.date()
six_hours_ago_hour = six_hours_ago.hour
time_to_set: time = time.min if six_hours_ago_hour < 12 else time(hour=12)

# combine `date` and `time` into a UTC `datetime`
dt = datetime.combine(six_hours_ago_date, time_to_set, timezone.utc)
# get unix timestamp
seconds = round(dt.timestamp())

print('Result:', dt)
print('Epoch ts:', seconds)
```

Result:

```
Input: 2022-05-17 04:00:00+00:00
Result: 2022-05-16 12:00:00+00:00
Epoch ts: 1652702400
```

Answer (score 1):

Reply I might do something like the following, after you calculate `six_hours_ago`:

```
six_hours_ago_midnight = datetime.combine(six_hours_ago, datetime.min.time())
if six_hours_ago - six_hours_ago_midnight >= timedelta(hours=12):
    return six_hours_ago_midnight + timedelta(hours=12)
else:
    return six_hours_ago_midnight
```